# Is there anything C++ can do better than D, or that D cannot do? (example of multiple inheritance)

Tags: c++, oop, multiple-inheritance, d

Recently I have become interested in learning about the D Programming Language. (Specifically D2, which at the time of writing is what people are referring to, as D the original is now in maintenance mode for compatibility with existing code.)

Before I decide whether to use C++ or D (I already know C++, I know nothing about D), I want to know is there anything that C++ does better than D? If you read about D online, there is a lot of material which simply says "here is an example of C++ code, here is an example of that code in D and look - it happens to be much better". Which of course is true for the examples shown.

Some of the differences may be subject to opinion. For example, calling a base class constructor from a derived class is done by `super()` (D) rather than `<class name>(args)` in an initialization list (After `:` notation.) (C++). Personally I don't like this `super` but that's just my opinion, and this is ***not*** the question I am asking.

More relevant is that D cannot support multiple inheritance. (!)

- What else does D NOT support which C++ does?
- Are there examples of things C++ does better in D for some syntactical or logical reason? (Not primarily opinion based, but feel free to respond with an opinion based argument if it is relevant and constructive.)
- Does the fact the D doesn't support multiple inheritances lead to situations where you are "locked out" of doing something which you could do in C++? (I am thinking maybe `iostream` / `ifstream` / `ofstream` operations?)
- Are there ways around the multiple inheritance ban if you really need it?

For example, one thing which you might want to do in C++ is something like the following:

```
class base
{

}

class base_has_read_operation
{
    public:
    void read()
    {
        // complicated read function, 100000 lines of code...
    }

    virtual void do_read() = 0;

    private;
    // data
}

class base_has_write_operation
{
    public:
    void write()
    {
        // complicated write function, 100000 lines of code
    }

    virtual void do_write() = 0;

    private:
    // data
}

class reader : public base_has_read_operation
{
    public:
    void do_read()
    {
        read();
    }
}

class writer : public base_has_write_operation
{
    public:
    void do_write()
    {
        write();
    }
}

class read_writer : public base_has_read_operation, base_has_write_operation
{
    public:
    void do_read()
    {
        read();
    }

    void do_write()
    {
        write();
    }
}
```

But presumably without multiple inheritance you can't do this?

Comment: This is interesting, but it seems too open ended for this site.

Comment: See here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97207/what-does-c-do-better-than-d

Comment: Welcome to the Turing Tar Pit, where everything is equivalent, but nothing of interest is easy.  You can implement D in C++ and vice versa: neither can do anything the other cannot.

Comment: Yeah, allocating polymorphic objects on the stack is one of them.

Comment: Allocating polymorphic objects on the stack is easy in D, it just takes two lines of code (one for making the stack array, one for putting the class in it) instead of the one line it takes in C++. Making sure references to it remain valid is a bit trickier, but similar to how you'd do it in C++ too.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe It takes one line if you've imported `std.typecons`: `auto val = scoped!MyClass()`

Answer (score 5):

Your multi-inheritance problem could be solved using a template mixin, in other word a piece of code that is emplaced into another. Example:

```
interface IWriter {
    void do_write();
}

// It is a template, you can specify compile-time arguments
mixin template Write() {
    // complicated write function
}

interface IReader {
    void do_read();
}

mixin template Read() {
    // complicated read function
}

// D has multiple interface inheritance
class ReaderWriter : IWriter, IReader {
    void do_write {
                      // You can do other things before...
        mixin Write;  // The code of Write is inserted here
                      // ...or after
    }

    void do_read {
        mixin Read;
    }
}
```

I could argue though that you surely would be better-off if your ReaderWriter had a handle to a reader and a writer instead of relying on over-coupling multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I've moved from C++ to D two months ago, so maybe I'm wrong.
The `ref` qualifier does not replace the references in C++. Especially with the C++11 rvalue references and forwarding you can do great efficiency stuff like only copying an parameter if it is necessary. One of the aspects of D I had problems with is the reference and value types. C++ is so much more transparent to this.
This makes it difficult to write efficient code. Assume you have some class `C!(T)`. You might want to create a `T`, but if `T` is a class, you need `T t = new T(arg)` otherwise `T t = T(arg)`. I've used a mixin and like `T t = mixin((is (T == class) ? "new " : "") ~ "T(arg)");`. This is rather ugly. In this case I'd prefer C++ value objects.

Comment: I think generic code that sometimes allocates a new object and sometimes doesn't is actually a mistake anyway since it has a potentially hidden cost... but you could get similar behavior anyway with `auto t = new T(arg);` which works with all types (including, I think, built ins like int...). That would consistently yield a reference type.

Comment: Now I have to deal with pointers; this is exactly *not* the thing I want. I always want the same type depending on ``T``, preferably ``T`` itself.
Can't it be done another way?